# Using PrincipalContext to create groups from SharePoint gives access denied for domain admin user

Tags: 2010, active-directory, access-denied

I'm trying to create new AD security groups from the codebehind of a SharePoint application page. I'm using

```
System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement
```

to do this. This is how I'm creating a group:

```
PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "mydomain", "myOU", ContextOptions.Negotiate | ContextOptions.Signing | ContextOptions.Sealing);
GroupPrincipal group = new GroupPrincipal(ctx, "ThisIsATestGroup");
group.Description = "Test";
group.GroupScope = GroupScope.Global;
group.IsSecurityGroup = true;
group.Save();
```

From my understanding this code should execute in the context of my user (which is a domain admin) and in LinqPad it does. I can create the group just fine. However in SharePoint I get "Access Denied" on

```
group.Save();
```

This is because the WindowsIdentity for the request is in fact the application pool account and not the actual user. Is it possible (and if so how) to impersonate the SharePoint user in a proper WindowsIdentity so I can access AD using PrincipalContext?

Edit:

```
WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent(); //This is the application pool account
```

I'm assuming that this is what is causing the problem, but I cannot seem to be able to impersonate the user correctly. I've tried (amongst others) this method: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/sharepointoccasionaltip/VHlRXiZWT8s/rMw-TbLK95cJ

Edit:
The method described above throws an exception when I try to create a PrincipalContext within the impersonated context: "Either a required impersonation level was not provided, or the provided impersonation level is invalid"

Edit:
I've confirmed that it's actually trying to connect using the app-pool account.

Comment: It should impersonate user logged in SharePoint by default when running code in application page codebehind. Do you have any extra impersonation/elevation code besides that part you provided?

Comment: No, I've stripped out everything in an attempt to find out why I'm having the issue. What you see is the only thing in the application page (inside Page_Load).